# Clone Postgres DB to other machine

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I would like to set up a complete clone of my Postgres DB on a different machine. I created a dump with pg_dumpall, but trying to restore it I get multiple errors:

```
psql:dump_04-10-2021_15_20_38.sql:24: ERROR:  current user cannot be dropped
psql:dump_04-10-2021_15_20_38.sql:33: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
psql:dump_04-10-2021_15_20_38.sql:92: ERROR:  option "locale" not recognized
psql:dump_04-10-2021_15_20_38.sql:95: ERROR:  database "template1" does not exist
psql:dump_04-10-2021_15_20_38.sql:97: \connect: FATAL:  database "template1" does not exist
```

I assume I first have to create the database, users, roles, etc. on the new machine. Is there a convenient way to do this? Can I create a complete copy without manually recreating everything before importing the dump?

Comment: What options did you use for pg_dumpall?

Comment: The 3rd line suggests you are using incompatible versions.  You need to restore onto the same version or higher than you dumped from.